# What is the Neo4j query run when click the expand button?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What is the query that neo4j executes when press the expand button on the neo4j browser node? [neo4j browser expand button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G20FJ.png)

My problem is that I want to get all the node/relationship that right next to the target node. However I tried the following cypher query

```
MATCH (x:LABEL {Name: "name"})-[r]-(y)
RETURN x, r, y
```

and apoc based query

```
MATCH (x:LABEL) WHERE x.Name = "name"
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(x, {maxLevel:1}) YIELD nodes, relationships
RETURN nodes, relationships;
```

None of these works as fast as press the expand button on the node. Actually, it's slower in a magnitude.

Neo4j version: 3.3.1

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The results of queries that return nodes (and/or relationshisp) include (among other things) the native IDs of the nodes.

When the neo4j Browser expands a node, the native `id` for that node is used to generate a query string from this template (as copied from the `getNeighbours` function in [the browser](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/blob/master/src/browser/modules/Stream/CypherFrame/VisualizationView.jsx#L99-L105)):

```
const query = `MATCH path = (a)--(o)
               WHERE id(a) = ${id}
               AND NOT (id(o) IN[${currentNeighbourIds.join(',')}])
               RETURN path, size((a)--()) as c
               ORDER BY id(o)
               LIMIT ${this.props.maxNeighbours -
                 currentNeighbourIds.length}`
```

As you can see, this query is doing a lot of work, but the native ID search (in the `WHERE` clause) gets the `a` node quickly, and once that is gotten its neighboring nodes (`o`) can be gotten quickly as well.

Your queries should be able to get quicker results if you had [an index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:LABEL(Name)`.

And, if you used the native ID directly (like the browser does), you should get even faster results (I assume `id` is passed as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/parameters/)):

```
MATCH path = (x)-[r]-(y)
WHERE ID(x) = $id
RETURN x, r, y
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Find the id first and then expand is critical. 

I found out that the reason my query to find the neighbor is so slow is that the neighbor node is more than 10k, which compared to the default neo4j (100) is too much. So I put a limitation to the number of neighbors to be queried back.